# My function returns an empty DataTable (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datatable

Im using VB.NET with Microsoft Access.

I'm having problems with a function that I created. I just want the function to return a DataTable full of information to make my report, with the parameters that I given. I 'm using the Between clause... I first thought that the clause "Between" not work with Access (Like "Limit"), but I created a query in Access, and works excelent!

Seeing this, I come to the conclusion that for some reason , my OleDbDataAdapter is not filling my DataTable as it should be ... and i cant see why, because I followed the same pattern like the others functions (With differents querys, obviously).

The code of the function is this:

```
Protected Friend Function reporte(ByVal tipo As String, ByVal fechInicio As String, ByVal fechFinal As String) As DataTable
    Dim cmd As String = ""
    Dim p As New DataTable
    If (tipo.Equals("general")) Then
        cmd = "Select Cod_Producto,Serial,Lotpallet,Fecha_Ingreso,Producto,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad From Productos WHERE Fecha_Ingreso BETWEEN '[" & fechInicio & "]' AND '[" & fechFinal & "]'"
    ElseIf (tipo.Equals("por producto")) Then
        cmd = "Select Cod_Producto,Serial,Lotpallet,Fecha_Ingreso,Producto,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad From Productos WHERE Producto='[" & PantallaPrincipal.REP.ComboModel.SelectedItem & "]' AND Fecha_Ingreso BETWEEN '[" & fechInicio & "]' AND '[" & fechFinal & "]'"
    End If
    Try
        con.Open()
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, con)
        adapter.Fill(p)
        adapter.Dispose()
        comando.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Problemas en la consulta: " + ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Return p
End Function
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I already use that, and didnt work. Also, My form dont have textboxs to do SQL Injections...

Comment: I do the test as you told me, and yes, my variables are storing the data succesfully as I programed

Comment: Dates are being stored and my query too

Comment: Look! The adapter fails to fill the DataTable! http://i.imgur.com/cawSQnK.png

Answer (score 0):

Well... apparently,  parameterized query was the solution... Perhaps I wrote it wrong ... I think I obfuscate.. Im sorry:

```
Protected Friend Function reporte(ByVal tipo As String, ByVal fechInicio As String, ByVal fechFinal As String) As DataTable
    Dim cmd As String = ""
    Dim table As New DataTable
    If (tipo.Equals("general")) Then
        cmd = "Select Cod_Producto,Serial,Lotpallet,Fecha_Ingreso,Producto,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad From Productos WHERE Fecha_Ingreso BETWEEN @fein AND @feed"
    ElseIf (tipo.Equals("por producto")) Then
        cmd = "Select Cod_Producto,Serial,Lotpallet,Fecha_Ingreso,Producto,Modelo,Descripcion,Precio,Cantidad From Productos WHERE Producto='[" & PantallaPrincipal.REP.ComboModel.SelectedItem & "]' AND Fecha_Ingreso BETWEEN @fein AND @feed"
    End If
    Try
        con.Open()
        comando = New OleDbCommand(cmd, con)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fein", fechInicio)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feed", fechFinal)
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(comando)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        comando.Dispose()
        adapter.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Problemas en la consulta: " + ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Return table
End Function
```

Thank you for your help, and sorry again Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå.